# Return a parameter of the same table

Tags: lua, lua-table

Let's say a table:

```
t = {
    { name = "Bob", age = 34, gender = "Male"},
    { name = "Bill", age = 40, gender = "Male"},
    { name = "Barbara", age = 20, gender = "Female"}
}
```

Using name as an index, what do I need to do to return or print the age of Bob or the gender of Barbara?

More precisely, a function to call for age and another for gender when the name is "Bob", or any other.

Comment: Your question, but not your table structure, implies names are unique. @lhf's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38291678/2226988) provides additional structure to the table based on this assumption. You might consider using that structure instead of the one you have. `t = { ["Bob"] = { age = 34, ...}, ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your table, do this once

```
for i=1,#t do
        t[t[i].name]=t[i]
end
```

Then you can access the fields using names:

```
print(t["Bob"].age, t["Bob"].gender)
```

Comment: To what this does, print the table like this: `for name, record in pairs(t) do print(name); for attribute, value in pairs(record) do print("", attribute, value) end end`

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to handle this. The obvious way is to just iterate through all the elements of the table until you find the right one:

```
function FindByName(name)
    for i = 1, #t do
        if(t[i].name == name) then return t[i] end
    end
    assert(false, "Could not find name " .. name)
end
```

So you would call `FindByName("Bob").gender` to get that particular field.

However, if you know you're going to be looking up by name a lot, you can modify your array to have the same keys by name. After building your array, call this function:

```
function MapToName(t)
    for i = 1, #t do
        t[t[i].name] = t[i]
    end
end
```

This will allow you to look the entry up with `t[the_name]`.

The downside of this approach is that, every time you add elements, remove elements, or change the names of elements, you will need to modify the table accordingly. If you change an element's name, then you have to set `t[old_name]` to `nil`, and set `t[new_name]` to the value.

But for a static table, this would be fine.